# file type not installed on this computer

Tags: windows-server-2008, perfmon, logfiles

We are currently experiencing some memory problems on one of our windows 2008 servers, so I want to log the processes and their memory use with perfmon as suggested elsewhere on this website, but when I select a logfile as data source I get the following error:

> "Data source (MyPathToLogFile) is either invalid or can not be found. System message: The specified log file type has not been installed on this computer."

This seems so trivial I hardly dare to ask this, but google was not much of help this time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what happens if you browse to "YourPathToLogFile"?

Comment: Perfmon asks where the logfile is located. After I browse to where the file is located and select the file, it gives me this message. Doesn't really matter what kind of log file type I choose (csv, blg, tsv), I keep getting it.